# How to get rating for each user?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a such type of relations in db.
[image: db relations image]

I wrote such SQL code to get list of user with their average rating.

```
SELECT
  c.id,l.login,
    AVG(f.mark) AS AVGRating
  FROM logininfo l
 INNER JOIN person p
   ON l.id = p.info_id
 JOIN candidate c
    ON p.id = c.id
  JOIN feedback f
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY AVGRating ASC;
```

Problem is that I get same rating for all users.

Comment: `join` on `feedback` is missing

Comment: @vkp thanks, should I delete question now?

Comment: You could select an answer to keep it clean and for someone else to benefit from similar questions.

Comment: @ThinkCode I will do it in 5min. People help very fast))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the join condition for the feedback table:

```
SELECT
  c.id,l.login,
  AVG(f.mark) AS AVGRating
FROM logininfo l
  JOIN person p
    ON l.id = p.info_id
  JOIN candidate c
    ON p.id = c.id
  JOIN feedback f
    ON c.id = f.candidat_id -- < -- this one
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY AVGRating ASC;
```

Btw, `INNER JOIN` and `JOIN` are the same.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
c.id,l.login,
AVG(f.mark) AS AVGRating
FROM logininfo l
INNER JOIN person p
ON l.id = p.info_id
JOIN candidate c
ON p.id = c.id
JOIN feedback f
--add a join condition
GROUP BY c.id
ORDER BY AVGRating ASC;
```